# MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.6 update causes php-cgi error: PDO issue?

Tags: database

I recently performed a MySQL upgrade on Windows Server 2008R2, moving from MySQL 5.1 to MySQL 5.6.22 (Community Edition). The server is currently using PHP 5.3.0.

Things went just fine for all my WordPress installs (no problems on cutover); however, all my Drupal 7 sites are now generating 500 errors (coming from php-cgi.exe via php5ts.dll from what I can tell).

To address concerns about the broad nature of the question, this is the specific Windows event log message:

> Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 5.3.0.0, time stamp: 0x4a492a25
>   Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.3.0.0, time stamp: 0x4a4929bb
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x0015e1b0
>   Faulting process id: 0x7bb4
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d01fa8dec6e9a6
>   Faulting application path: C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\PHP\php5ts.dll
>   Report Id: 2e661541-8b9c-11e4-a303-001b210e0a6a

I've checked database credentials, time zone defaults, and haven't changed IIS settings, folder permissions, or anything of that nature.

The one difference that stands out is that Drupal uses PDO for access, and I'm wondering if there is a potential issue there with the version being used, since all these sites worked fine with MySQL 5.1.

PDO seems to be showing version 5.0.5-dev (rev 1.3.2.27).

I can't locate anything that leads to identification, troubleshooting or resolution.

(I'm off to try to replicate with just a simple PDO test.)

Has anybody encountered this and/or have documentation that might help isolate/resolve things?

NOTE: The closest I've come is to somebody using PDO drivers for MSSQL (not MySQL) where there was a faulty Drupal layer on top of PDO. Details here - http://forums.iis.net/t/1181446.aspx?PHP+5+3+8+Problems

---

UPDATE:

Not PDO...

The following example (with real values) works fine.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME';
$username = 'USER';
$password = 'PASS';
$options = array();

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

if ($dbh) {

    $stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM MYTABLE LIMIT 1');
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    print_r($results);

}
else {
    echo 'Failed.';
}
```

---

UPDATE 2:

I have double checked any options set by the prior install of MySQL 5.1 that might not have been carried over. I realize more things are auto-set and defaults might have changed, which could be part of the issue.

The other issue that might come into play is changing the server collation default from **utf8** to **utf8mb4** ... It looks like Drupal 7 should support this (discussion, in the framework of Drupal 8 goes back to 2011 - https://www.drupal.org/node/1314214). The tables continue to show ut8 collation, so data should be unaffected.

MySQL 5.6 does introduce **explicit_defaults_for_timestamp** but I haven't been able to find anything implying it should be an issue either (setting 0/1 results in the same error).

Comment: What error do you get?  Without that we can't help you.

Comment: I'd add this as an answer, but it turns out **utf8** vs **utf8mb4** was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, the whole thing was resolved by pushing the default character set back to **utf8** from the incompatible (for Drupal, but not for WordPress) **utf8mb4**...

Relevant my.ini settings as follows:

```
[client]

default-character-set = utf8 # not utf8mb4

[mysql]

default-character-set = utf8 # not utf8mb4

[mysqld]

# REF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24487309/3174018
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci 
character-set-server = utf8 # not utf8mb4
```